# AS3: How would I take a character from one string variable and append it to a textField?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to AS3 and Stack Overflow, so if my question isn't clear I apologize.

I'm having a problem with this String project I'm working on, basically, I'm trying to access a specific character from a String variable, and then append that to a text field.

I've dug through the AS3 Documentation a bit, and found an appendText() method, but I have no clue what to research if I want to access something from a string variable (I'm hoping for a way so I can access the character as if I was accessing a value from an array, such as test[4])

Any support will be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use for example : [`String.charAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charAt()) ...

Comment: It works now, thanks for your help!